# Joining two files in C#, split options

Tags: c#, file, split, stream, streamreader

I am currently trying to work on files, joining multiple of them and having problem because the last work from file 1 is linked with first word from file 2. For example:

File 1:John has got new haircut

File 2: Mike has got new haircut

and it prints me "haircutMike".

The code I am using to split words:

```
        input.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(n =>{});
```

I am also making one big file from multiple ones like so:

```
string[] files = { "f1.txt", "f2.txt" };
        FileStream outputFile = new FileStream("new.txt", FileMode.Create);

        using (StreamWriter ws = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
        {
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                ws.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file) + " ");
            }
        }
```

@EDIT

Changed some code, of course I meant to use stream not binary,also I am using split because I want to count the number of each word in files so I have to split spaces, dots etc.

You mentioned to use + " " option, although it works, but it added me 1 letter to the total count.

Comment: ws.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file) + " "); Firstly you don't explain what you want to happen... secondly why are you using split at all?

Comment: Currently you're treating the files as *binary* data. (It's not clear why you're using `BinaryWriter` rather than just a `Stream`, mind you.) Where does splitting words come into it? Note that if you had a line break at the end of file 1, you wouldn't have the issue - although you might end up with a Unicode Byte Order Mark half way through the file, which wouldn't be good.

Comment: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'string'.

Comment: Oh wow, I just checked I am using binary writer instead of streamwriter, wow. Give me a second, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Edited my question a bit, the + " " option works, although you asked why am I splitting, I am doing this to count words, for example in file 1 "John is my cousing" in file 2 "John" and I want to count John = 2, etc. When I do + " ", it makes my program add " = 1" (yeah blank space = 1).

Comment: @Ken'ichiMatsuyama If it adds one letter to the count, why not take 1 away from the count? i.e. 1 x the number of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** for multiple input files:

```
 string[] files = { "f1.txt", "f2.txt" };

 var allLines = files.SelectMany(i => System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(i));

 System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("new.txt", allLines.ToArray());
```

Comment: This example is for two files, although I am going to use like 100+ files in normal program..

Comment: @Ken'ichiMatsuyama OK I'm going to edit, however using this idea you can solve your problem.

Comment: It worked, thanks, gotta check SelectMany documentation, thanks Hossein.

Comment: @Ken'ichiMatsuyama If you use the `Select`, the result would be an array of array of strings but you are going to use all lines together and save them in a file, so you should flatten those arrays, in this case `SelectMany` do the job for you.